Expectation of a random variable and its reciprocal
Consider two RV $X$ and $Y$ which are both strictly positive.
If $E(X)>E(Y)$, does this also imply that $E(1/X)<E(1/Y)$?

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.

Let $$ X=\begin{cases} 1 & \ \textrm{ with probability 1/2 } \\ 2 & \ \textrm{ with probability 1/2},\end{cases}$$ and $$ Y=\begin{cases} 100 & \ \textrm{ with probability 1/100 } \\ 1 & \ \textrm{ with probability 99/100}.\end{cases}$$
Then $\mathbb{E}X = \frac{3}{2} < 1.99 = \mathbb{E}Y$. But $\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{X} = \frac{3}{4}$ while $\mathbb{E}\frac{1}{Y} > 99/100$.

On the same theme: $\mathbb P(X=2)= \mathbb P(X=\frac12)=\frac12$ and $\mathbb P(Y=1)=1$.  Then $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[\frac1X] =\frac54 > 1 = \mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb E[\frac1Y]$ - an example of the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

If X and Y are in (0,1) instead? is this still not true?
